# Для чего используют совсем пустой for(;;); в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

У кого-то в коде видел такую странную конструкцию последней строкой в блоке:

```
    /* какой-то код - пропущен */

    for(;;);
}
```

К сожалению, сейчас не найду, где именно такое встретилось, но запомнилось своей необычностью. Бесконечный цикл с пустым оператором, или он как-то оптимизируется и выполняет иную роль?

Для чего могла понадобиться такая конструкция, и как она выполняется?

Comment: зацикливание, sleep

Comment: @norbornen, это какой-то бесконечный `sleep`. Он браузер убьёт скорее.

Comment: да, он бесконечный. по этому нужно смотреть это выражение в контексте

Comment: Каков бы ни был контекст, JS ведь в один тред выполняется – значит, из этого цикла выхода нет. Если только не web worker'ы, может?

Comment: не хочу гадать. в вебвокере слабо представляю кейс для которого это потребуется. могу выдумать кейс типа держать лонгполлинг соединение, а могу предположить что это просто ошибка разработчика в условном операторе в который никто не заходит. в любом случае сама запись канонична, пример есть [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for#Optional_for_expressions)

Comment: Скорее пример [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008030/a-for-loop-without-any) более подходит.. Хотя  чисто `for(;;);` наверное действительно надо в применяемом контексте рассматривать. Возможно перед этим какой-нибудь `if` располагается

Comment: [Why does Google prepend while(1); to their JSON responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2669690/2881286)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался / нашёл [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058401/empty-for-loop-in-facebook-ajax)! Это делается для защиты от включения скрипта в страницу и дальнейшего использования данных из него.

Answer (score 5):

Есть разные причины для использования бесконечных циклов. Из наиболее часто встречаемых, есть 2 типа:

- Event loop

Такое чаще-всего встречается в играх или desktop-приложениях. Принцип состоит в том, что программа реагирует исключительно на пользовательские действия или наружные проишествия, и сама по себе не рассчитана на натуральный выход из этого цикла. Пример (для демонстрации принципа):

```
for (;;) {
    switch(pending_event){
         case key_pressed:
             // Отреагировать на нажатую клавишу
             break;
         case mouse_moved:
             // Отреагировать на движение мыши
             break;
         case new_data_available:
             // Отреагировать на новые данные (например в групповой игре)
             break;
         case exit:
             // Процедура выхода
             break;
    }
}
```

В мире веба такое встречается ОЧЕНЬ редко, потомучто большинство javascript-кода написано асинхронным способом (эветны, кол-бэки), специально для того, чтобы избежать такого рода циклы. В традиционном desktop-программирование они являются центральным элементом приложения.

- Нетривиальные условия выхода

Это встречается чаще, и представляет собой цикл где условия выхода многочисленные или не простые. В таких случаях используются альтернативные методы выхода (`return`, `exit`, `goto`, итд). Такого рода код писать не рекомендуется и очень часто усложняет понятливость программы; гораздо лучше, например, использовать переменное (`is_continue_loop`) для правильного контроля над циклом. Тем не менее, такой паттерн используется относительно часто.

Comment: Это понятно. Но во встреченном мной примере в цикле **отсутствуют** какие-либо действия, условия, выход. Он буквально выглядит так: `for(;;);`. Ума не приложу, как может осуществляться выход из неё, кроме как по принудительной остановке «подвисшего» скрипта браузером?

Comment: @Sergiks Тогда это и вправду очень странно. Может быть оригинальный автор что-то тестировал (напр. как быстро браузер завершит процесс принудительно), и забыл убрать оттуда этот код? Это единственное что приходит в голову.